# JSON Request displaying console issue

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to get the console.log to work with the 'interests' information using the following JSON request but I get the following error message in the console.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.getJSON ('https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all'), function(data) {
consol.log(data.interests)
}
</script>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You've spelled `console` wrong for a start.

Comment: you posted the answer "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSONP (http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/), you won't get console.log working until you fixed the cross origin error

more info: [What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)

Answer (score 0):

there is an issue with your parantheses

```
 $.getJSON ('https://app.citizenspace.com/api/2.3/json_consultation_details?dept=parliament&id=ddcengage&fields=all', function(data) {
      console.log(data.interests)
 });
```